# How do I make the timer continue to countdown even if you reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code works fine without a button. I don't know how to do this with a button, so that when I click the button the timer works normally even if I reload the page. When I use a button the timer stops counting down if I reload the page.

```js
var test = 3600;
$('button').click(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("counter")) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("counter") <= 0) {
      var value = test;
    } else {
      var value = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    }
  } else {
    var value = test;
  }

  $('#divCounter').text(value);

  var counter = function() {
    if (value == 0) {
      localStorage.setItem("counter", test);
      value = 0;
    } else {
      value = parseInt(value) - 1;
      localStorage.setItem("counter", value);
    }
    var minutes = Math.floor(value / 60)
    var seconds = value % 60
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds
    $('#divCounter').text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  };

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="divCounter">59 : 59</p>
<button>Start The Counter</button>
```

Comment: Consider saving the current countdown in session storage along with the current time,  then use that to figure out how much time is left, and then restart the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work as you require you can simply check what the current value is in localStorage. If it's not `0` then you know the countdown has been started and you need to set it going again automatically when the page loads.

To make this simpler I would strongly suggest you refactor the logic to separate each action in to its own function to enable them to be called from various places, ie. on load, or on button click.

You can also make some parts of the logic more succinct. Try this:

```js
let start = 3600;
let current = localStorage.getItem("counter") || 0;

let countDown = () => {
  if (current <= 0) {
    localStorage.setItem("counter", start);
    current = 0;
  } else {
    current--;
    localStorage.setItem("counter", current);
  }
  let minutes = ('00' + Math.floor(current / 60)).slice(-2);
  let seconds = ('00' + (current % 60)).slice(-2);
  $('#divCounter').text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
};

let startCountdown = () => {
  countDown();
  let interval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
}

$('button').click(function() {
  if (current != 0)
    return;
    
  $('#divCounter').text(current);
  startCountdown();
});

if (current != 0)
  startCountdown();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jg41uL53/)

See the snippet for a working demo as the SO snippet editor does not allow access to localStorage.

Comment: Not working and timer doesn't work when clicking the button! thank you, Sir:)

Comment: Check the console in your local version. You can see this logic works fine in the fiddle demonstration.

Comment: It works but I don't want the the timer start to countdown itself when page reload.

Comment: I want timer works only with btn click, and I just want the timer keep continuing to 0 If I refresh the page or close it.

Answer (score 0):

Just run a check for localStorage item `counter` and trigger a click, that's all you're missing:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("counter")) {
    $('button').trigger('click')
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this just restart the counter?

Comment: @evolutionxbox restart the counter from where the user left , yeah !

Comment: Right. When I first read the question it didn't use local storage... (or so I thought)